# UIView Subclass not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have an XCode project I am working on that has multiple views controlled by a tabBar that is throwing multiple instances of the error:

```
"cannot find interface declaration for '~my sub view name~', superclass of '~my sub view name~'
```

These sub views were created after the original project as new files.  Each has a line of code like this:

```
@interface meViewAndEdit : meViewAndEdit
```

I see no #import statements either.  The project fails to build and I am not sure what i should be setting these to. Should I be referencing my App delegate as the superclass? what is missing here?

---

**UPDATE:** (updated)

I changed the interface statements for each of my header files for the views i created as follows

@interface friends : UIView

BUT, it seems that i have a new issue that i'll have to research:

"UIView" may not response to "initWithNibName.bundle"

This is now present in each of the .m files for the views I created.

still learning, thanks in advance for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When declaring a class in Objective-C, you need to specify the class name, as well as the superclass. In your code `@interface meViewAndEdit : meViewAndEdit`, you are essentially declaring a class that is a subclass of itself. Since you are trying to create a subclass of `UIView`, the class declaration should look as follows: `@interface meViewAndEdit : UIView`.

Also, in a comment in another answer, you asked whether or not you need to `#import` the app delegate in every class. The answer to this is usually no, unless you specifically need to access something involving your specific app delegate class.

I will also make note that it is conventional to give classes **a capitalized name**. For example, it should be `MeViewAndEdit`, rather than `meViewAndEdit`. You only should keep the first letter lowercase if it is the name of a variable or function.

**EDIT:** The reason that you are encountering the errors in your update is that you are trying to subclass UIViewController, not UIView. On top of this, instead of subclassing either one, you are subclassing the app delegate. Change your line of code `@interface subviewname : my_app_delegate` to `@interface subviewname : UIViewController`. You are trying to create a subclass of `UIViewController`, not `my_app_delegate`.

On another conventional note, it is *never* good to put underscores in a class name. Always name classes in camel case like `MyAppDelegate`, not `my_app_delegate`.

Comment: Excellent, I will implement these modifications and respond with status.

Comment: meh .. same issue as listed i the update above .. "UIView may not respond to "... pretty much every defined function in the .m file to do with loading or memory alloc.

Comment: my update was not accurate as i had changed it before posted.  most recent update reflects current issues.

Comment: ok .. UIViewController seems to ahve addressed the issue .. though for some reason my main window xib doesnt load. i'll keep researching

Comment: Turns out I restarted and used the TabBar, the UIViewController, and some tweaking and it's working now .. much thanks for your direction

Answer (score 0):

You need to `#include` the .h header files in all classes in which you are using them.

Comment: it's the .h header files where I am getting the errors.  Do all of the sub-views need to include the app delegate header, or am i supposed to be referencing the app delegate as the superclass perhaps?